# Execute method every 15 seconds until it works

Tags: c#, timer

I want a methode to check every 15 seconds if a specific device is connected/the driver for it used.

So something like:

```
Every 15 seconds 
{
if (Device is connected)
  {
   do sth.;
   exit loop;
  }      
}
```

So far I was able to create a Timer that seems to work:

```
{
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
timer.Interval = 15000;
timer.Elapsed += CheckConnection;
timer.Start();
}
```

Unfortunatly I have no real clue how to exit/abort the timer once my CheckConnection Method is true/find the device connected.

Comment: Stop the timer? Just set `Enabled` to `false`? If `CheckConnection` were to return `true` or `false` depending on whether it succeeded or not, you could use this `Elapsed` delegate: `timer.Elapsed += (s, e) => { if (CheckConnection()) timer.Stop(); };`

Comment: have a look at the [Stop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.stop?view=net-5.0) method

Comment: @GM Have you considered to use [Polly's Retry](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample application which shows how you can use [Polly's Retry policy](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry) to achieve the desired behaviour.

Let's suppose your `Device` class looks like this:

```cs
public class Device
{
    private int ConnectionAttempts = 0;
    private const int WhenShouldConnectionSucceed = 7;

    public bool CheckConnection() => ConnectionAttempts == WhenShouldConnectionSucceed;

    public void Connect() => ConnectionAttempts++;
}
```

- It increases `ConnectionAttempts` each time when the `Connect` method has been called.
- When the attempts counter equals with a predefined value then the `CheckConnection` will return `true` (this simulates the successful connection) otherwise `false`.

The retry policy setup looks like this:

```cs
var retry = Policy<Device>.HandleResult(result => !result.CheckConnection())
    .WaitAndRetryForever(_ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
        onRetry: (result, duration) => Console.WriteLine("Retry has been initiated"));
    
var device = new Device();
retry.Execute(() =>
{
    device.Connect();
    return device;
});
```

- Until a given device is not connected (`!result.CheckConnection())` it will retry for ever (`WaitAndRetryForever`) the `Connect` method.
- Between each retry attempt it waits 15 seconds (`TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)`).
- The `onRetry` delegate is used here only for demonstration purposes. `onRetry` is optional.

So, if I have the following simple console app:

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var retry = Policy<Device>.HandleResult(result => !result.CheckConnection())
            .WaitAndRetryForever(_ => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15),
                onRetry: (result, duration) => Console.WriteLine("Retry has been initiated"));

        var device = new Device();
        retry.Execute(() =>
        {
            device.Connect();
            return device;
        });
        Console.WriteLine("Device has been connected");
    }
}
```

then it will print the following lines to the output:

```
Retry has been initiated
Retry has been initiated
Retry has been initiated
Retry has been initiated
Retry has been initiated
Retry has been initiated
Device has been connected
```

Comment: 3rd party component to do what regular `while` can do? Seriously?

Comment: @Dennis My assumption is that the provided problem scope is highly reduced in order to be well-focused. For this simple use case it is true that this solution wastes one's shot, but I suspect that the exact problem is way more complex where tool like this can become handy.